# How to fill missing even numbers in an array of odd numbers concisely?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I've the following arrays of odd numbers:

```
const oddNums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
```

And I want to fill it with the missing even numbers to obtain the result below:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

I've done it like this and it works fine, but can it be done in a more concise manner, maybe using array methods?

```
const oddNums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const nums = [];
for (let i=0; i<oddNums.length; i++) {
  nums.push(oddNums[i]);
  nums.push(oddNums[i] + 1);
}
console.log(nums);
```

**Note:** The odd numbers would always be in sequence but might not begin with `1`, for ex: `[11, 13, 15]` is a valid array. And the output for `[11, 13, 15]` should be `[ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ]`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `for` loop and any other options will just be further abstraction of this. Though `push()` actually accepts any number of arguments, so you could simplify to a single push `nums.push(oddNums[i], oddNums[i] + 1);`

Answer (score 3):

The only information you need is the first (odd) number and the size of the input:

```js
const oddNums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

const result = Array.from({length: oddNums.length*2}, (_, i) => i + oddNums[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):**

```js
const 
  oddNums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
  nums = oddNums.flatMap(n => [n, n + 1]);

console.log(nums);
```

**Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):**

```js
const 
  oddNums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
  nums = oddNums.reduce((r, n) => r.concat(n, n + 1), []);

console.log(nums);
```

**Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):**

```js
const 
  oddNums = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
  nums = oddNums.reduce((r, n) => (r.push(n, n + 1), r), []);

console.log(nums);
```

Comment: just `push()` concat returns a new array on every iteration. `r.push(n, n + 1), r`

Comment: @JSCoder keep in mind that on large arrays your `for` loop is going to be far more efficient, and the only option above that comes close is the last option using `reduce` and `push`